# How to display menu options after Long press on android app icon like paytm and swiggy?

Tags: android

How to display menu options after Long press on android app icon like paytm and swiggy? Is there any tutorial to accomplish this above task.

Comment: That is known as context menu. check for that

Comment: Hello pankaj  can u share link for same?

Comment: Here is tutorial https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/android/create-shortcuts-android-application-show-menu-long-press-app-icon/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Shortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/) are what you need.

```
ShortcutManager shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
ShortcutInfo shortcut = new ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "id1")
    .setShortLabel("Website")
    .setLongLabel("Open the website")
    .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.icon_website))
    .setIntent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.mysite.example.com/")))
    .build();
shortcutManager.setDynamicShortcuts(Arrays.asList(shortcut));
```

Comment: how i can create multiple shortcuts with respective intents

Comment: How to implement with React Native app where main activity having multiple screens. Screens are navigating with react-navigation. Should I use deep linking to open the screens?

Comment: Is there any way to be notified when the shortcuts are displayed? i.e. using Shortcuts to be notified when the launcher shortcut is long pressed?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. To display your items add your code in onLongClick() method... Hope this will help...!

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final View view = findViewById(R.id.add_item);

        if (view != null) {
            view.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

                    // Do something...

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Long pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }
});

return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}